# getServerSideProps called on state change

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, getserversideprops, next-redux-wrapper

I'm using getServerSideProps with next-redux-wrapper.
The issue is it invokes when I change the state on the button click.

as of my understanding, it should invoke only when we visit the page directly or navigate through the next link or route.

here is the code of getServerSideProps

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async (context) => {
    const session = await getSession(context);
    const state = await store.getState();

    if (!session) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/auth/signin",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }
    const permitedModels = session.permissions.map(
      (permission) => permission.model.name
    );
    const permited = checkAccessibilty(state.investor.Models, permitedModels);
    if (!permited) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }

    store.dispatch(setFieldPermission([]));
  }
);
```

here is my store configuration

```js
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import investorSlice from "./investorSlice";
import permissionSlice from "./permissionSlice";
import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({ investor: investorSlice, permission: permissionSlice });

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
        
      const nextState = {
        ...state, // use previous state
        ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
      };
      debugger
      return nextState;
    } else {
      return combinedReducer(state, action);
    }
  };

const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: reducer,
  });
};
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

On the button click I'm only updating the state.
here is code

```js
  const clickHandler = () => {
    if (!ctx.mode) {
      ctx.setActiveMode("create");
    } else {
      ctx.setActiveMode("edit");
    }
  };
```

not able to find a reason behind the behavior.